# Application random crash on recent 2017 iPad, A1822

Tags: objective-c, crash-reports

Recently, my app got frequent crash on the iPad Model A1822, iOS 10.3.0. It runs well on old models with same iOS 10.3.0.

The crash seems related to NSArray autoreleasing.

What may cause this kind of crash? Is there anyone having the same issue?

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000020
Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183c717f4 objc_object::release() + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001851e29a4 common_removeAllObjects + 156
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850d69e0 -[__NSArrayM dealloc] + 28
3   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000183c72134 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 836
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ceb18 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 28
5   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018519ece4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1580
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001850ced94 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 424
7   GraphicsServices                0x0000000186b38074 GSEventRunModal + 100
8   UIKit                           0x000000018b380130 UIApplicationMain + 208
9   fairapp                         0x0000000100024490 main (main.m:16) + 17552
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001840dd59c start + 4
```

EDIT

The crash only happens on the specific A1822 model.

Comment: If you haven't done so already, try setting an Exception Breakpoint in Xcode to find out more info on the crash.

Comment: @Koen An exception breakpoint will not catch EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

Comment: Most likely, this is caused by an over-released object.

Comment: @bbum: Thanks for pointing that out, I did not know that.

Comment: the crash only happen on the specific A1822 model